# node.js on VirtualBox CentOS machine, no connection?

Tags: node.js, centos, virtualbox, remote-debugging

I've setup a CentOS 6.3 Box in a VirtualBox Machine, installed node.js and npm and wrote an example 'Hello World' Application which listens on port 8080 and IP '192.168.10.132' (this is the IP of the CentOS machine). The server starts correctly, but under 192.168.10.132:8080 on my host machine (Mac OS X 10.0.7) I always get an error.

Did I something wrong?

Comment: I think this will help you https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I run into issues like this because I have not opened the port in iptables.

The following command will add the port to iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "node.js port"
```

Then make sure to save your current config.

```
service iptables save
```

then you'll need to restart iptables

```
service iptables restart
```

For more info, check out the iptables docs here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about the firewall rules. You saved my evening :-)